# C++: sorting/alphabetizing methods

Tags: c++, sorting, scripting, methods

OK, I have been looking for weeks now. I have looked through [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), but all the plugins for this sort of thing is for Java or C# and not C++. [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) does not work, nor does [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/). How in the world can I sort my methods in a .cpp file without having to go in and cut and paste by hand (there are hundreds of files and there is not enough time in the world to do that)?

I have tried writing the program myself, but I am not very skilled in scripting and have zero experience in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). Creating the program in C++ I believe is possible but if there is a simpler way then I would like to know.

Comment: I suppose you have too many god-objects if you think that sorting your methods alphabetically helps.

Comment: i don't think it helps or anything. Its not my code, not my files. I was told "do this" and i want to find a way to do it without killing myself in the process.

Comment: However: Writing a _general_ solution yourself from the ground up is pretty hopeless. Example: `template <typename T, int I>
template <typename X>
Foobar<T,I>::Frob<X>
Foobar<T,I>::Frob<X>::x()` <- that's a valid function header. One could make it excessively more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked for a long time and talked to many co-workers and am now convinced we should not do it. Too many headaches and one of the developers said he didn't want that because of the way he writes his code. Thank the lord he said something!

If anyone else is looking to do this and trying to find a solution, I would just like to let you know that it is not worth the trouble. If you HAVE to do something like this in C++ then you have got to do it by hand. Pray that you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use it but take a look at [Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/). It is a plugin for Visual Studio. I am sorry, I saw now that it is also only for C#. I thought that it worked with C++ too. Sorry.

Comment: no worries, that was one of the first ones i looked into also, got it setup and everything only to find that out lol.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you've concluded you don't want to do this, but just in case someone else does, you might be able to use [Doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) to do the "heavy lifting" and extract the functions from your source.

You can configure Doxygen to extract the code structure from undocumented source files.

You'd then have to extract starting line numbers of the functions from Doxygen's output, sort, and reassemble. It gets messy because you might need to introduce forward declarations.

Thankfully you decided against doing it.